# How to check if route with specific routename is registered in global.asax

Tags: asp.net, routes, url-routing

i have registered some routes in my global.asax:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("route1", ...);

routes.MapPageRoute("route2", ...);

routes.MapPageRoute("route3", ...);
```

how can i check in my application if the routes (e.g. 'route2') exist?

i can find the route in the collection:

```
System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes
```

but i cannot find a routename. how can i filter or search in the colection. do i have to check for the url parameter to check if the route exists or is there a more comfortable way?!

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can i filter or search in the colection.

As far as I know, you can't, unless you use some workarounds when mapping your routes to store the route name in some datatoken :

see for example

[How can I get the route name in controller in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/363211/1236044)

and

[How do I get Route name from RouteData?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3954669/1236044)

Comment: yes, you are right, i didn't find a solution that was ok for me, so i wrote my own route extension with a routename and now i can check with linq if the route exists... thats works fine. thx!